# How can bytes be shoved back into a Read implementing type in Rust?

Tags: stream, rust

Is there a `Read` stream type in the standard library that supports "shoving" bytes back into the stream, such that a subsequent read would return said bytes first, before other bytes in the stream?

```
n = stream.read(&mut buf).unwrap();
if ... {
    stream.???PUT_BACK???(&buf[..n])
}
```

Comment: Is `stream` limited to a `Read` trait or can you choose a more concrete type?

Comment: Any type is acceptable as long as the underlying source of bytes can be any object that implements `Read`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the problem the other way around: how can I only read some bytes in certain cases. Then you can use the [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) trait:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn main() {
    let f = File::open("/etc/hosts").expect("unable to open");
    let mut f = BufReader::new(f);

    {
        let bytes = f.fill_buf().expect("cannot read");
        println!("{:?}", bytes[0]);
    }

    if some_condition() {
        f.consume(2);
    }

    {
        let bytes = f.fill_buf().expect("cannot read");
        println!("{:?}", bytes[0]);
    }
}
```

---

In rare cases where you need to add data that *wasn't* part of the original source, then using `chain`, as [Florian Weimer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45521127/155423), is likely more appropriate. In the rarer cases where that doesn't work, you can write what you need:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, Read};
use std::cmp::min;

/// Warning: lightly tested; never shrinks
struct PushableRead<R> {
    extra: Vec<u8>,
    offset: usize,
    inner: R,
}

impl<R> PushableRead<R>
where
    R: Read,
{
    fn new(inner: R) -> Self {
        Self {
            extra: Vec::new(),
            offset: 0,
            inner,
        }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) {
        self.extra.extend(bytes)
    }
}

impl<R> Read for PushableRead<R>
where
    R: Read,
{
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let extra_bytes = self.extra.len() - self.offset;

        if extra_bytes > 0 {
            let to_copy = min(extra_bytes, buf.len());

            let dst = &mut buf[0..to_copy];
            let src = &self.extra[self.offset..self.offset + to_copy];

            dst.copy_from_slice(src);
            self.offset += to_copy;
            Ok(to_copy)
        } else {
            self.inner.read(buf)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = File::open("/etc/hosts").expect("unable to open");
    let mut f = PushableRead::new(f);

    f.push(b"This is extra junk");

    let mut data = Vec::new();
    f.read_to_end(&mut data).expect("Unable to read");

    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&data));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [`chain` method of `std::io::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.chain) and its example (slightly modified here):

```
fn main() {
    use std::io::prelude::*;
    use std::fs::File;

    let f1 = File::open("foo.txt").unwrap();
    let f2 = File::open("bar.txt").unwrap();

    let mut handle = f1.chain(f2);

    let mut buffer = String::new();
    handle.read_to_string(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", buffer);
}
```

There is no way to do this with the original `Read` object because the trait simply does not provide this facility.  If you need some form of lookahead, you need to look at the [`BufRead` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) or the [`BufReader` struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html), although its lookahead support is quite limited.